# Kendo UI Grid Filters data not updating

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

Maybe someone can help me with this issue that I have...

My Kendo UI Grid

```
$("#grid").kendoGrid({            
        dataSource: {
            data: self.positions(),
            pageSize: 50
        },
        filterable: true
    });
```

where self.positions() is a knockout observable Array that gets populated via ajax Get.

My problem now is when I refresh my positions observable array and rebind the new data to the grid, the columns filters are not refreshing the data properly.
My filters still showing the old positions data.

Any help???

Kendo UI DOJO Example:
http://dojo.telerik.com/oVOsi/31

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calling a `query` on the grid datasource and clearing the filters/resetting any other attribute on the datasource works for me (with an additional check to ensure filters exist).  Something like:

```
var grid = $("#grid").data("kendoGrid");
var gridDataSource = grid.dataSource;
var filter = gridDataSource.filter();
if (filter) {
    gridDataSource.query({ filter: {}, pageSize: 10, page: 1 });
}
```

**EDIT**
Now I understand the exact requirement, you can rebuild the grid on each button click (so the column filters are rebuilt according to the data). I have put together a dojo example:

[Dojo example of rebuilding grid](http://dojo.telerik.com/OrIci)

Comment: Sorry but doesn't work for me. Could you send me a dojo where the filter is binding the  right data? Tks

Comment: The examples @ezanker and I have sent through will successfully clear the filters applied to the `grid` when `myOtherBtn` is clicked.  However, what you are looking for (I think) is to rebuild the grid columns with the new filters applied to the columns containing the new grid data? In which case you may need to rebuild the grid itself, so that the filters contain the relevant data.

Comment: I have updated my answer and provided a dojo example for you

Comment: No problem @RicardoCoelho

Comment: Thanks a lot. I was not using pagsize & page while applying the custom filters or resetting the filters here which was creating a huge performance & other issues. It saved a huge time for me.

Answer (score 5):

I found this solution which works nicely :

```
    var grid = $("#grid").data("kendoGrid"); 
    grid.setDataSource(grid.dataSource);
    grid.dataSource.read();
```

The trick is to use the method "setDataSource()", it will reset all the filters.

http://dojo.telerik.com/oVOsi/103

Comment: This was the solution that work for me. Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score -1):

Try clearing the filter on the datasource object:

```
$('#myOtherBtn').click(function(){
  var grid = $("#grid").getKendoGrid();    
  grid.dataSource.data(products2); 
  grid.dataSource.filter({});
  grid.refresh();
  grid.sync();
});
```

Comment: Thanks, but I had tried before that option but no joy!

Comment: @RicardoCoelho, for me your dojo works. Click get products, set a filter, then click get other data. Filter is gone and all rows show up.

Comment: @ezanker : His Dojo doesn't work. The Filters are not updated when you switch products. This is the issue.